# EXTRUDE - is this the best way to simulate separate wooden planks on vertical face

Tags: extrude

In an effort to try and make the face of a vertical surface represent 2 planks of wood, one above the other I thought of the Extrude tool which I have never used before.
I had no trouble using the tool (except for some strange reason moving now jumps preset distances instead of smoothly so I have to hold the CTRL key while dragging) BUT I cannot work out how to select each part to mark the seams for applying texture.  Is there a better method and if not how do I select each part separately. I have included an image to try and explain what I mean - the large top object in the view.  Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I would recommend you watch this series of tutorials by Blender Guru where he teaches the basics of modeling and texturing by guiding you through the modeling of a chair. Notice how the seat is a curved plank and the edge texture is made to look like several wood 'slices' one on top of the other, I think it's a little bit like what you are trying to do. But I recommend watching the whole thing because he covers a lot of important stuff regarding modeling:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hf2esGA7vCc&ab_channel=BlenderGuru

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I have watched quite a few videos by Blender Guru but not that one and it is a bit over my head having only started 3D modelling one week ago. Since asking the question I now think I would probably be better using an array (of 2 on the Z axis) with no space between each and add offset textures on each. What I am wanting to do is create a vertical surface to look like two separate long wooden planks of wood one above the other. It is actually a model of a floating dock and the sides are of two wooden planks one above the other.

Comment: if it "jumps" preset distances, you should uncheck this little guy here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stknn.png (blue icon)

Comment: Hey @JohnArnold I really think you should give the tutorial a try. It's a beginner's tutorial and he guides you step by step, just watch closely what he does. Pause the video and go back if you have to. I promess, by the end of the series of tutorials you will have a set os skills that will help you when you are doing your own projects like this one.

Comment: As for your question, extruding the plank would be fine, you'd just have to edit the UVs (the 'mapping' of the texture) to adjust the texture. Making an array of 2is also fine, or  to simply duplicate the plank and move it up would be fine too. There are many options that give basically the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding jumping. I had been holding the CTRL key while moving which got me around the 'problem'.     I have watched heaps of tutorials as already mentioned including your suggestion.      This is more to do with what (is the easiest) function to use rather than how to use it. That is why the subject is "Extrude - is this the best  way..."     I have answered my question below (I used an array to achieve what I wanted). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found using an ARRAY solved my problem.
I created an array with a count of 2 on the Z axis with an offset large enough so that I could see the 2 separate objects one above the other.
I then selected the bottom object and added a material
Then I unwrapped the object and used the UV editor to ensure all faces were horizontal.
Next I set the UVs Offset U to 0.1 to ensure the 'pattern' from my material texture image was slightly different on the object above.
Lastly I moved the two objects in the array back together.